# Ansible pip module: name package and umask 0022 Fatal error: invalid literal for int() with base 8: '18' umask must be an octal integer

Tags: pip, ansible, ansible-2.x, octal

ansible/ansible-playbook version: 2.1.2.0

I have the following action in my playbook:

```
- name: Install cli (as well)
  pip:
    name: "{{ mycompany_pip_pkg }}"
    umask: 0022
```

Why am I getting the following fatal error message even though I followed the docs for Ansible `pip` module: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/pip_module.html

**Error:**

```
TASK [company.company-ansible : Install cli (as well)] ****************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "details": "invalid literal for int() with base 8: '18'", "failed": true, "msg": "umask must be an octal integer"}
```

Ansible `pip` Docs says:

> The system **umask** to apply before installing the pip package. This
>   is useful, for example, when installing on systems that have a very
>   restrictive umask by default (e.g., 0077) and you want to pip install
>   packages which are to be used by all users. Note that this requires
>   you to specify desired umask mode in octal, with a leading 0 (e.g.,
>   0077).

http://programtalk.com/vs2/python/749/ansible-modules-core/packaging/language/pip.py/ shows the following code:

```
if umask and not isinstance(umask, int):
    try:
        umask = int(umask, 8)
    except Exception:
        module.fail_json(msg="umask must be an octal integer",
                         details=to_native(sys.exc_info()[1]))
```

**PS:** The following syntax WORKS! but why the above one is not working?

```
- name: Install cli (as well)
  pip: name="{{ mycompany_pip_pkg }}" umask=0022
```

**UPDATE:**
Question:
1) Why in Ansible `pip` module, when `name` property's value contains an  invalid package name, then this module is failing for `umask` property's value (which is correct in my case)?

Comment: ok, I found the solution but still, why the first section's syntax is not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible expects arguments to modules in `key=value` format, even though the free-form (YAML style) arguments are still accepted but not recommended.

From [Conventions/Recommendations](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dev_guide/developing_modules.html#conventions-recommendations)

> Modules can also take free-form arguments instead of key-value or json
>   but this is not recommended.

Comment: I agree. Wondering why they would mention the same in their documentation, see their last example. If I use the free-form YAML syntax without using `umask: 0022 or umask: ... property`, it's working. I have used free-form YAML syntax in other playbooks for other modules and they all work. I think `pip.py` needs to be fixed for `umask` property. The advantage I see using the free form YAML is better indentation / user read friendly syntax -vs- putting all property/variables in one line.

Comment: I provided an update to my post and now my post is asking a valid question :) (which I found after doing some investigation) hope you can provide some light.

Comment: I don't think the words "free-form" apply to YAML-style here. Do you have any reference for that? Including a clear statement that YAML-style is not recommended? I think free-style refers to, for example `local_action` module, in which you can specify the module either as a key-value or directly in a `local_action`'s value.

Answer (score 3):

Just enclose the *umask* value in quotes.

Doesn't work:

```
  pip:
    name:
      - pika
      - argparse
    umask: 0022
```

Does work:

```
  pip:
    name:
      - pika
      - argparse
    umask: "0022"
```

The same problem used to occur with "file" module until it got fixed with https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9196. As others pointed out, using *key=value* syntax works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the umask in quotes worked for me.
      pip:
    name: uwsgi
    state: present
    umask: '0022'

```
# ls -lah /bin/uwsgi -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1.3M Jan 21 12:12 /bin/uwsgi
```

Comment: Yep, I did the same: `pip: name="{{ pip_pkg }}" umask="0022"` but on the same line, not free form yaml form way